# how to avoid the "useless split in void context" warning in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, split

this is my code:

```
my %hash=();

while (<DATA>) {
    split /\=|,/;
    $hash{$_}++;
}

map{print "$_ == > $hash{$_}\n"} sort keys %hash;

__DATA__
1=2,3,4
a=1,1,5
```

I don't know why it warn me :
**Useless use of split in void context at get_path.pl line 11."**

and how should I change the code to avoid this warning?
thank you~~~~~

Comment: What is the purpose of `split` there?

Comment: this script intend to count the same items.and these items delimited by = or ,

Answer (score 4):

You're not doing anything with the return value of split; $_ when used in '$hash{$_}' is the line being read from DATA:

your hash after the while loop is:

```
%hash = (
          '1=2,3,4
' => 1,
          'a=1,1,5
' => 1
        );
```

Also note the new lines at the end of the keys.

Edit: Question updated with comment:
"this script intend to count the same items.and these items delimited by = or , –"

The way to do this would be to modify your while loop to this:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp ;
    foreach(split /\=|,/){
        $hash{$_}++;
    }
}
```

split returns an array split on '=' or ',' - this is then looped over and a hash keyed on that value is incremented

Comment: thank you, `$hash{$_}++ for split /\=|,/`  and the warning disappeared now

Comment: make sure you chomp, or you'll get two keys depending on if it is end of line or not eg - $hash{4\n} is not the same as $hash{4}

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to count occurances of any string in DATA then the following will do what you want.  The return of split needs to be returned to an array and then you can process the array.  You could do the loop in a single line, but this way is more detailed.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash=();

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @arr = split /\=|,/;
    map {$hash{$_}++} @arr;
}
print Dumper \%hash;

$VAR1 = {
      '4' => 1,
      '1' => 3,
      'a' => 1,
      '3' => 1,
      '2' => 1,
      '5' => 1
    };
```

To do this in one line

```
map {$hash{$_}++} split /[=,\n]/, while <DATA>;
```